# How to perform a query and assign result without producing results in query

Tags: mariadb

In a stored procedure I am performing the following:

```
    SET @txtSQL := CONCAT("SELECT @bintTicketsRemaining := COUNT(*)",
                          "FROM `", txtTable, "` WHERE state IS NULL;");
    PREPARE STMT FROM @txtSQL;          
    EXECUTE STMT;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
```

The assignment to `@bintTicketsRemaining` works fine, however a result is also returned to the caller which I don't want, how can I stop this and still get the assigned value into the variable?

I'm using mariadb from 11.2.2-MariaDB, client 15.2 for osx10.17 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper.

Similar to an echo statement in the console where you can redirect the output to NUL which prevents the the content from appearing in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, changed the query to:

```
    SET @txtSQL := CONCAT("SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @bintTicketsRemaining ",
                          "FROM `", txtTable, "` WHERE state IS NULL;");
```

Which does exactly what I want, the count value is assigned to the variable and there is no output to the caller.